# Place Formulas (setFormula) on SpreadJS headers (colHeader)

Tags: javascript, spreadjs

I currently have a solution using AngularJS/SpreadJS where we need to update the header section with a formula.  When we change a cell value in the header using setValue everythign displays ok, however we need to display a formula using setFormula, in these cases the formula gets calculated and displayed in the rows belonging to the actual sheet where my data is at.

```
//Does not work and displays in row 2 of the sheet:
sheet.setFormula(2, i, formula, GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);

//Displays value in actual header in teh correct location/header cell                
sheet.setValue(2, i, 'my formula!', GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);
```

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain the use case for this.  This won't be easy since the header is not part of the calcengine dependency tree.    If you provide more detail, i'll have our team look into this.   Is it possible to use the sheet itself as a header, i.e. place the formula in the top row then freeze the top row pane then hide the header itself.

Comment: Thanks!  We have a dynamic header where we display the aggregation from our columns.  Our spreads can have 1000 records, hence the users are asking to have aggregations on the top.  We already started development and have place all our headers in the colHeader.  We currently populate our sheet with a simple setDataSource(ourData), how can we set this to then start populating everything (data column headers, data etc) on a particular row?  Looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented below solution to achieve the SUM formula in Column Header of the spread sheet.This function can be called on spread sheet events like cellChanged,clipBoardPasted to achieve functionality.

```
   var spread = new GC.Spread.Sheets.Workbook($("#ss").get(0), { sheetCount: 2 });
    var displaySheet = spread.getSheet(0);
    displaySheet.setRowCount(2, GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            displaySheet.setValue(i, j, i + j);
        }
    }
    $("#btnSetAutoTotal").click(function () {
        setTotal(displaySheet, 0);
    });

   function setTotal(sheet, columnIndex) {
    var formula = "SUM(R[1]C[1]:R[10]C[10]";
    value = GC.Spread.Sheets.CalcEngine.evaluateFormula(sheet, 'SUM(A:A)', 0, 
   columnIndex, false);   
   sheet.setValue(0, columnIndex, value, GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The team created this sample to demonstrate what you need.   Hope this helps.

```js
        function setColumnHeaderFunction() {
            this.name = "SetColumnHeader";
            this.maxArgs = 3;
            this.minArgs = 3;
        }
        setColumnHeaderFunction.prototype = new GC.Spread.CalcEngine.Functions.Function();
        setColumnHeaderFunction.prototype.description = function () {
            return {
                name:"SetColumnHeader",
                description: "The function will apply the calc result on specified column",
                parameters: [{
                    name: "result",
                    description: "The value which will be setted on column"
                }, {
                    name: "rowIndex",
                    description: "The row index"
                }, {
                    name: "colIndex",
                    description: "The column index"
                }]
            }
        }
        setColumnHeaderFunction.prototype.evaluate = function () {
            var value = arguments[0], rowIndex = arguments[1], colIndex = arguments[2];
            var spread = GC.Spread.Sheets.findControl("ss");
            var sheet = spread.getSheet(0);
            sheet.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, value, GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var spread = new GC.Spread.Sheets.Workbook($("#ss").get(0), {sheetCount: 2});
            spread.addCustomFunction(new setColumnHeaderFunction());
            var displaySheet = spread.getSheet(0);
            displaySheet.setDataSource(getSource(100));
            displaySheet.setRowCount(3, GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);
            displaySheet.setValue(0,0,"Count:",GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);
            displaySheet.setValue(0,3,"Sum:",GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);
            displaySheet.setValue(0,4,"Average:",GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);
            displaySheet.setValue(0,5,"Sum:",GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);


            var calcSheet = spread.getSheet(1);
            calcSheet.visible(false);
            calcSheet.setFormula(0, 1, "SetColumnHeader(SUM(Sheet1!D:D),1,3)");
            calcSheet.setFormula(0, 2, "SetColumnHeader(AVERAGE(Sheet1!E:E),1,4)");
            calcSheet.setFormula(0, 3, "SetColumnHeader(SUM(Sheet1!F:F),1,5)");
            calcSheet.setFormula(0, 4, "SetColumnHeader(COUNT(Sheet1!A:A),1,0)");
        });

        function getSource(count) {
            var dataList = [];
            var _lines = ["Computers", "Washers", "Stoves"];
            var _colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "White"];
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                dataList.push({
                    id: i,
                    line: _lines[parseInt(Math.random() * 3)],
                    color: _colors[parseInt(Math.random() * 4)],
                    price: parseInt(Math.random() * 501 + 500),
                    cost: parseInt(Math.random() * 601),
                    weight: parseInt(Math.random() * 101),
                })
            }
            return dataList;
        }
```